# Overloading conversion operator from int to std::string

Tags: c++, operator-overloading, std

Is it possible to overload conversion operator from int to std::string? Is it possible to use this function:

```
void printToLog(std::string text);
```

Like this:

```
int a = 5;
printToLog(a);
```

Or this:

```
int a = 5;
printToLog(a + " bombs have been planted.");
```

?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There's a function for it in the standard library. The aptly named [`std::to_string`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/to_string):

```
int a = 5;
printToLog(std::to_string(a) + " bombs have been planted.");
```

You cannot add a conversion operator for this purpose. Such an operator can only be a member of a class type, and `int` is not a class type. Neither can you add a converting constructor to `std::string`. Use the mechanism the standard gives you.

Comment: I know, but I'm asking: Is it possible to make conversion operator from int to std::string?

Comment: @lollypap54 - No. And why would one do that? To avoid some typing? It's a  bad reason.

Comment: Well yeah, it's pretty bad for this exact purpose, but sometimes you just want to know: is it possible? :/

Comment: @lollypap54 - Like I already said. No.